# Is it possible to estimate the posterior distribution of the difference of two means using published t statistics?

Tags: bayesian, t-test, meta-analysis, posterior

I am interested in using summary statistics from published papers to obtain posterior distributions for the difference of two means. In the setting of the classic t-test, we can imagine measurements of some characteristic y for two groups. Often people want to make claims about the difference between the means of these groups dm = mean(y1) - mean(y2). One way to do this is a hypothesis test against the null hypothesis dm = 0. I am interested in whether there is a way to estimate a posterior distribution of dm using published results from t-tests, such as the observed t statistic, p-value, and degrees of freedom for the t-test. I would also like to apply a similar method to F-tests with df1 = 1 by taking the square root of the F statistic as a t statistic, but I'm not sure if this is valid. It would also be nice to have a method that can apply to multiple kinds (e.g. two-sample unequal group sizes, paired) of tests.

I have considered using methods related to inference on normal distributions (e.g. by assuming y1 and y2 are normally distributed). From reading up on this, it looks like there might be nice methods that use conjugate priors to give nice closed form solutions for the posterior in the case of inference on normal distributions, but I'm not sure if it is possible to extract all the necessary information with the information that is typically published. For example, often the group sample sizes or even the sample mean difference are not included in publications. Any thoughts?

Comment: Good idea, but you're right that you can't do this without sample sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Neil G. Unfortunately it seems that people often don't report the sample sizes. It is somewhat more common to report the degrees of freedom for the t-test. Do you think it is possible to use other information to reasonably approximate a posterior? For example, you might be able to guesstimate group sizes by using degrees of freedom and assuming equal samples. Obviously this won't be 100% accurate, but it might at least be a reasonable approximation.

Comment: @Neil G and others, I would also be interested in what people think would be a good method if other information (e.g. sample sizes) were included. Some publications have more information than others, so it would be interesting to see what is the minimal information/assumptions required to actually find a reasonable method.

Comment: Isn't the number of degrees of freedom related to the sample size?

Comment: @ Neil G yes, but it is not nessesarily the case that the sample size(s) can be exactly determined from the degrees of freedom. For example, consider a two sample unpaired t-test with groups of different sizes (n1 =/= n2). the degrees of freedom for the standard test is df = n1 + n2 - 2, so it is not possible to determine n1 and n2. For equal samples it is possible, so a work around might be to approximate by assuming equal samples. I also wonder if there is some other work around that avoids this issue, such as my exploring the fact that you only care about the difference between the groups.